# lewis structure of O3

Tags: lewis-structure

This is my first question, sorry if I don't know how to write a good question.

why is O3 shaped like this?:[image]

and not shaped like each Oxygen molecule is connected to two other molecules?
(i did not find an image for that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (non)existence and (in)stability of molecules is related to the energy of the configuration. And it just so happens that the configuration of O3 that you show is more stable than "cyclic ozone". This might be because of the strain, which would appear in a three-membered ring (similarly to the strain in cyclopropane).

However, the molecule has been studied theoretically, or at least the wikipedia page says so. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_ozone)